# Should layered use of crypto always have a cryptographic binding between the layers?

Tags: protocol-design, tls, multiple-encryption

Reading the latest [TLS weakness](https://secure-resumption.com/), it seems that multiple weaknesses have been found over the years caused by not ensuring that messages are sent over the same channel, and in general a lack of cryptographic bindings between messages and layers.

I wonder if there is some general rule in all of this.  For example if data is encrypted inside an encrypted channel, should for example the key material for the two be bound somehow?

Comment: I think in the case of your example, the key material should be generated independently, but could be cross authenticated against eachother (via signature)